# Attempt to de-reference a null object on an existing object

Tags: apex

I have the following method that runs on beforeUpdate and beforeInsert Triggers on Event:

```
private void populateMeetingStatus()
{
    System.debug('populateMeetingStatus');
    for (Event event_i : (List <Event>) Trigger.new)
    {
        if(event_i.Event_Details__C != null)
        {
            if(event_i.Meeting_Status__c == 'Completed')
            {
                //"Event Locked" - The field should be True if Meeting status is Completed
                System.debug('event_i.Event_Details__c:' + event_i.Event_Details__c);
                System.debug('event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c:' + event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c);

                event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c = true;

            }
            else
            {
                //"Event Locked" - The field should be false
                event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

it fails on the line

```
event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c = true;
```

with the error

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

i printed the value of this field:

```
10:22:49:172 USER_DEBUG [1512]|DEBUG|event_i.Event_Details__c:a1G9E000000InGTUA0
10:22:49:172 USER_DEBUG [1513]|DEBUG|event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c:false
```

this fiels exists, and still i receive this error. why does this occur? how can i solve it?

Comment: You need to add a null to lookup field before accessing lookup’s field.

Comment: @RahulSharma What do you mean add a null?

Comment: Before accessing the reference field with ‘__r’ do a nill check on ‘__c’ field like ‘event_i.Event_Details__c != null’

Comment: updated the code, still occurs

Comment: I've added a handful of duplicate questions that should provide the information you're looking for. Relationships are not available automatically, but instead you have to query for them. You also need an explicit DML update in order to save those changes. There's plenty of other questions on this site as well with similar answers, so please take some time to do a search or two for the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use "after Insert" and "after Update" trigger events. Why because in below line you are referring Parent Object field

```
     event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c = true;
```

Use system.debug to find the value of that statement

```
 system.debug('event locked >>>>'+ event_i.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c);
```

and Also refer below links:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000063739&type=1.

and also  make method "Public" once  for Testing Purpose(Itsnt important but just try it)

Something liKE THIS:

```
 trigger EventdetailsUpdate on yourobjectApi(after insert,after Update){
 if((trigger.isInsert||trigger.isUpdate)&&trigger.isAfter)){
   EventClass.eventDetails(trigger.new);
   }




    public class EventClass{
     public static  void eventDetails(List<yourobjectApi> eventList)
  {
     set<id>acid=new set<id>();
List<Event_Details__C> eventList=new List<Event_Details__C>();
for (Event event_i:eventList))
{
    if(event_i.Event_Details__C != null  )
    {
        if( event_i.Meeting_Status__c == 'Completed')
        {
              acid.add(event_i.Id);
       }    
 }}
              List<Event_Details__C> eventList=[select id,Event_Details__C from Event_Details__C where event_i.Event_Details__C in:acid];
       for(Event_Details__C ev:eventList){ 
        ev.Event_Details__r.Event_Locked__c = true;
         eventList.add(ev);}
            if(!eventList.isempty()){update eventList;}}
                 }
```

Comment: The code sample is inaccurate, because Meeting_Status__c is part of event, but i took your idea and modified it. thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay No problem..I dont know your object structure  ..its brief Idea I had given to you.Thanks